# Use interposed functions selectively

Tags: c, gcc, dynamic-linking

I am interposing standard library functions. I have created a function in my lib for `close` function. However, I want to use it only for files and not socket, i.e. I want to selectively use it in some cases. If I have loaded interposed lib using `LD_PRELOAD=./customlib.so`, how do I use standard lib function instead of interposed one?

Comment: Why not call the lib function from your interposer if it's not of interest? `if(socket) close(fd); else {..} `. You can use `fstat` to find out whether `fd` is socket.

Comment: Exactly what I wanted to know. Thanks :)